# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS update error

Tags: updates, lts, 18.04

When I look for new upgrades this message pops up. I haven't received any updates after installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS stable release on my system.

[Error messages!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJlkU.png)

Comment: Try changing your mirror to US instead of Canada. You can search this site for instructions. US site could be missing files too though.

Comment: "Cannot resolve hostname" (you should put error messages as text and not as pictures) means you have either a name resolution problem or the resource you are trying to use does not exist anymore (or you have a typo in the name)